# Woocommerce Tab Styling Not Updating

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I am trying to fix the wrapper that surrounds the tabs on this woocommerce product page.

This is what is somehow is being generated:

```html
<div class="woocommerce-tabs wc-tabs-wrapper trx-stretch-width scheme_light inited" style="position: relative; box-sizing: border-box; left: -139px; width: 1278px; padding-left: 139px; padding-right: 139px;">
```

I personally tried editing the css files and manually editing the tabs.php file to look like this:

```html
<div class="woocommerce-tabs wc-tabs-wrapper" style="position: relative; box-sizing: border-box; left: -1px; width: 800px; padding-left: 139px; padding-right: 139px;">
```

But for some reason it just keeps reverting back to the first way. I'm losing my mind. Of course I can fix it in chrome via inspect, but I cant find the source file to edit.

Here is the page in question: http://ddr.kinsta.com/shop/clothing/ddr-joggers/

Thanks.

Comment: Is your theme overriding `tabs.php`?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I feel like I have went over every php, css and js file and cannot find anything that could be overwriting it.

Comment: Well you can confirm whether it's the theme or not by switching to a default theme. If it still happens that it could be a plugin. I thought it might be Javascript, but disabled JS on your page and it still occurs.